# Why my jump list is not working?

Tags: vim

When I keep typing `<C-O>`, it can only jump back 3-4 positions and then back to the first place again.

Here are outputs of `:jumps` when I pressing `<C-O>` for multiple times:

1 . When opening a file:

```
:jumps
 jump line  col file/text
  96     1    0 ~/works/WebContext.h
  95     1    0 ~/works/WebProcessProxy.messages.in
...
   3     1    0 ~/works/view_messages.h
   2  1896    4 ~/works/view_messages.h
   1     1    0 set viminfo='20,\"50    " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more
>
```

2 . Pressed `<C-O>`:

```
:jumps
 jump line  col file/text
  96     1    0 ~/works/WebContext.h
  95     1    0 ~/works/WebProcessProxy.messages.in
...
   3    59    4 ~/works/DOMWindowFileSystem.cpp
   2     1    0 ~/.vimrc
   1   115   44 ~/.vimrc
>  0     1    0 // Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
   1  1896    4 ViewHostMsg_DidCreateInstance,
```

3 . When `<C-O>` pressed again, the output of `:jumps` back to the same as the first step.

Output of `viminfo` is:

```
viminfo='100,<50,s10,h
```

Why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The `>` is at the right place, see `:h jumplist`. The default length of the jumplist is 100, 4 is indeed strange. What is the output of `:set viminfo`?

Comment: Having this same exact issue. Loading `vim -u NONE` fixes this, so there is something on my vimrc messing this up. No idea what could be though.

Comment: @Nacht So keep halving your .vimrc until, by the process of elimination, you find the perpetrator line.

Comment: Bisected my dotfiles git repo. It seems, in my case, it was a plugin called dbext.vim that broke how my jumplist worked. OP might want to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by these lines in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/ocaml.vim`:

```
" Get the modeline because folding depends on indentation
let s:s = line2byte(line('.'))+col('.')-1
if search('^\s*(\*:o\?caml:')
  let s:modeline = getline(".")
else
  let s:modeline = ""
endif
if s:s > 0
  exe 'goto' s:s
endif
```

When switching to a different file, this would jump to the start to read the modeline, adding to the jumplist.